# Cursor position not displaying correctly on custom range slider built with Vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, css-animations

I have built a custom input range slider using Vue.js.

Everything is working as expected except the cursor position when sliding the range slider is not in the correct place.

- The expected behaviour is that the cursor position follows the green
  thumb of the slider.
- What actually happens is while sliding, the    cursor appears ahead
  of the thumb.

For the purpose of the question, I have omitted some things for brevity:

Here is a preview with the endpoint removed (so expect some unrelated errors in the console):

https://zingy-malasada-3836bf.netlify.app/

Here is the code for the range input. As you can see I'm binding the style with values I get from an endpoint to calculate the **width** and **transform** values. This all works as expected, but I can't understand why the cursor position is off.

```
<div class="range-container">
                            <div
                                class="wrap"
                                :class="{ invalid: isExceedMonth }"
                            >
                                <input
                                    type="range"
                                    class="range2 calc-range"
                                    value="value"
                                    :min="duration.min"
                                    :max="duration.max"
                                    v-model="duration.amount"
                                    @input="onChange2"
                                />
                                <div class="track2">
                                    <div
                                        class="track-inner2"
                                        :style="{ width: duration.amount == duration.min || isExceedMonth ? `${0}%` : `${ duration.amount / (duration.max/100) }%` }"
                                    ></div>
                                </div>
                                <div
                                    class="thumb2"
                                    :style="{ left: duration.amount == duration.min || isExceedMonth ? `${0}%` : `${ duration.amount / (duration.max/100) }%`, transform: duration.amount == duration.min || isExceedMonth ? `translate(-${ 0 }%, -50%)` : `translate(-${ duration.amount / (duration.max/100) }%, -50%)` }"
                                ></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="calc-flex mt-30" v-cloak>
                                <p class="min">{{ duration.min }}</p>
                                <p class="max">{{ duration.max }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Furthermore, when I inspect the code in dev tools, and remove **track2**, and **thumb2**, keeping just the input (opacity needs to be changed to 1 instead of 0 for testing). as you will see the thumb and cursor work as expected, however the two colours (yellow and gray) will obviously not work in this scenario. I'm not sure what it is about the custom code that creates this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looked like my calculation was slightly incorrect:

Original:

```
left: loan.amount == loan.min || isExceedMoney ? `${0}%` : `${ loan.amount / 100 }%`
```

Updated to:

```
left: loan.amount == loan.min || isExceedMoney ? `${0}%` : `${ (loan.amount - loan.min) / (loan.max - loan.min) * 100  }%`
```